# The location of an individual object in JVM Heap Space

Tags: java, jvm

I am able to monitor the java application with various tools at JVM level. I can dump heap objects and find out the number of the objects and their total size.

At this point, I would like to know the heap location of each object, I mean, as you may know that there are three heap sections (eden, old, perm spaces), at the time of dump which object located at which heap space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of an individual object is not something you can trace.  Just dumping the heaps can result in the objects moving.  Whatever you are trying to do I suggest you do another way.

BTW: If you do a dump of "live" objects this triggers a full GC which can move all objects into the old gen, so in that situation you know where all the objects are. ;)

Comment: So we can say that I could not trace the location of individual object.

Comment: No and if you have enough objects to matter I suspect you wouldn't want to. e.g. millions.  What problem are you trying to solve as there may be a different solution?

Comment: Actually I currently have not any problem to solve. I believe that Tracing could be the best way to learn how JVM allocate objects and how GC works

Comment: What you can do is slowly create retained objects and watch them migrate from the eden to survivor to old gen. You can use `VisualVM`, `jstat -gccause {pid}` or `-verbosegc`